# Webview doesn't work?

Tags: android, webview

I want to pass URL string from main activity to second activity and load the URL in second activity.... but when I click the go button at mainactivity it goes to second activity but it shows nothing but blank.

here is my code ..

MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button go;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText=findViewById(R.id.urltext);
    go=findViewById(R.id.button6);


    final String link=go.getText().toString();

    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Webview.class);
            intent.putExtra(link,1);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



}


}
```

Second activity:

```
public class Webview extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    String one = getIntent().getExtras().getString("1");
    String http="https://";
    String url=http+one;

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
}
```

Comment: What is a first parameter of `Intent.putExtra` ? Did you at least take a look at documentation?

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras().getString("1");` Where did you think you put a String "1" in the extras?

Answer (score 0):

No offence but you must have read the documentation first .

> intent.putExtra(key,value);

Key should be constant in case of getting value from the same key in other component.So the answer is your OnClick shold be like below.

```
final String link=go.getText().toString();

go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,Webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("link",link);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Getting url from intent in other activity.

```
 String one = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
String http="https://";
String url=http+one;// Use this url to open in web view
```

Comment: thanks bro. and yes I should have read the documentation carefully

Comment: If this answer helps you in any way . Then accept it .

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to cast vote..btw my problem is still here I posted it below